# Splitting a comma separated string MySql

Tags: mysql

## table1

```
+-------+------------------------+
| ename | work_place             |
+-------+------------------------+
| john  | CA,philadelphia        |
| carl  | New Jersey,oklahoma    |
| paul  | New Jersey,oklahoma,CA |
+-------+------------------------+
```

Here is the code what im working with :
(I have tried jumbling the order of conditions in the code but no use)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test2`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test2`()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE str_len INT;
DECLARE temp_str text DEFAULT '';
DECLARE tr_name varchar(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE tr_wp varchar(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE exp_cur CURSOR FOR Select ename,work_place from table1;

DROP Temporary Table if exists temp_explode_string;
CREATE Temporary Table  temp_explode_string (emp_name varchar(11), wp varchar(55)) ;

Select count(*) into @name_cnt from table1;

open exp_cur;

get_wp: LOOP

fetch  next from exp_cur into tr_name,tr_wp;
set j=j+1;

SET str_len=LENGTH(tr_wp);  
SET i = round((LENGTH(tr_wp)-LENGTH(REPLACE(tr_wp, ',', '')))/LENGTH(',') + 1); 

WHILE(cnt < i) DO
SET cnt=cnt+1;
SET temp_str = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tr_wp, ',', cnt), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tr_wp, ',',cnt - 1)) + 1), ',', '');
Insert into temp_explode_string values (tr_name,temp_str);  
END WHILE;


IF j=@name_cnt THEN 
            LEAVE get_wp;
        END IF;

END LOOP get_wp;

CLOSE exp_cur;

select * from temp_explode_string;
select @name_cnt;

END$$
```

What im getting is this

```
+----------+--------------+
| emp_name | wp           |
+----------+--------------+
| john     | CA           |
| john     | philadelphia |
| paul     | CA           |
+----------+--------------+
```

The result what im looking for is

temp_explode_string

```
+----------+--------------+
| emp_name | wp           |
+----------+--------------+
| john     | CA           |
| john     | philadelphia |
| carl     | New Jersey   |
| carl     | oklahoma     |
| paul     | New Jersey   |
| paul     | oklahoma     |
| paul     | CA           |
+----------+--------------+
```

Could anyone help me out !
Excuse me, if any basic mistakes at code as im new to cursors.

Comment: If you want to do this as a stored proc, one bug that I can see is that you do not reset the value of cnt for each row you process. Ie, the first row is processed fine (as cnt is initialised to 0), but on the 2nd row it is 2 when the while loop starts, and there are only 2 items in that list so the WHILE condition is met immediately and the loop bypassed. For the 3rd row there are 3 items in the list, so it loops around them starting at the 3rd one (ie CA).

Comment: Got it !! guessing, how did I miss that ! Thanks once again.
Now two approaches for the same result !
Thank You once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this by joining against some sub queries that get a range of numbers:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT ename AS emp_name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.work_place, ',', 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10), ',', -1) AS wp  
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
```

Note this will cope with up to 100 comma separated values in any one work_place row.

This saves needing to use cursors, or anything other than a basic query.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help. If you need to cope with more than 100 values it is easy to add an extra cross join to go up to 1000 (or more if you want!).

Comment: Ya, i tried that too..any ways its more than sufficient as of now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BEGIN

       DECLARE pos1 INTEGER;
       DECLARE var1 VARCHAR(255);
       DECLARE var2 VARCHAR(255);
       DECLARE varFinal VARCHAR(255);
       DECLARE list1 VARCHAR(255);
       DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR Select ename,work_place from table1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    DROP Temporary Table if exists temp_explode_string;
    CREATE Temporary Table  temp_explode_string (emp_name varchar(11), wp varchar(55)) ;

    OPEN cur1;
    REPEAT
        FETCH cur1 INTO var1, var2;
        IF NOT done THEN

            SET list1 = var2;
            SELECT LOCATE(',',list1) INTO pos1;

            WHILE (LENGTH(list1) >0) DO
                IF (pos1=0) THEN
                    SELECT list1 INTO varFinal;
                    SET list1 = '';
                ELSE
                    SELECT SUBSTRING(list1,1,pos1-1) INTO varFinal;
                    SELECT SUBSTRING(list1 FROM pos1+1) INTO list1;
                    SELECT LOCATE(',',list1) INTO pos1;
                END IF;

                Insert into temp_explode_string values (var1,varFinal);

            END WHILE;

        END IF;

    UNTIL done
    END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cur1;

    select * from temp_explode_string;


END
```

Comment: Glad to be able to help. :)